# Stop cite footnote and dot switching positions

Tags: citing, footnotes

LaTeX changed position of dot, why?

please see the below example

```
to the third dimension\cite{Ref13}.
```

and the result:

[image]

The dot was supposed to be on the right of the footnote.

Some important parts of my Latex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{spieman}  % 12pt font required by SPIE;

%\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{spieman}  % use this instead for A4 paper

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{lineno}

\usepackage{xcolor, soul}

\sethlcolor{green}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{cleveref}



%%%%% References %%%%%

\bibliography{report}   % bibliography data in report.bib

\bibliographystyle{spiejour}   % makes bibtex use spiejour.bst


\vspace{1ex}

\noindent Biographies and photographs of the other authors are not available.

\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: some cite commands are clever and implement the style that the citation should be after punctuations. As you didn't gave a complete example, I can't tell you how to avoid it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In order to help you, we need to see as small *complete* document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that shows the described behaviour. At the left bottom corner, click on the `edit` button and add the source code.

Comment: As Ulrike and gernot already mentioned, a question like this can only reasonably be answered if we know how you produce your citations (i.e. which citation/bibliography packages are involved). This is best shown in a short example document, often called MWE - short for minimal working example - that reproduces the output you show in the question with as little preamble and body code as possible, while still being compilable for everyone who doesn't have your files. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864 explain more details.

Comment: The code shown so far is not compilable: It is missing a `\begin{document}` and appears to consist only of two separate code snippets. We also don't have your `.bib` file. I could not find the document class you are using `spieman` on CTAN, so please also tell us where we can find it (a link to the source where you got it would be best, so we can be sure we are talking about the same file). Please read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 for more help on creating MWEs.

Comment: The link of paper templete : https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/documents/Journals/spie-journal-papers-latex.zip

Comment: As you can see, there is similar problem in the temple of journal paper.

Comment: If that's how the journal's template does it, then you don't want to change it.

Comment: The reviewer wanted it :)

Comment: You are allowed to respond: "This is how the template does it."  If the reviewer still insists, the editor gets the final say.  If the editor wants you to do something against the template, then you are within your rights to ask them to change the template.  Coming here for help is even further down that list of things to do.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a deliberate design decision: the class `spieman.cls` does
`\RequirePackage[super]{cite}`. The package `cite` describes this behavior for the `\cite` command with the `super` option.

> trailing punctuation is moved to come before the superscript citation

It also says

> You may disable movement with the [nomove] package option.

The authors of `spieman.cls` decided not to do that so I can only repeat: this looks like a *deliberate design decision*.

Anyway, in order to prevent the behavior (and in order to avoid the option clash error) one needs to do either

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{nomove}{cite}
```

or

```
\RequirePackage[super,nomove]{cite}
```

*before* `\documentclass{spieman}`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{nomove}{cite}
\documentclass[12pt]{spieman}

\begin{document}

to the third dimension\cite{Alred03}.

\bibliography{report}
\bibliographystyle{spiejour}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much